# Cant delete rows in a dataframe python 3 . Value error: truth value ambiguous

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, boolean, valueerror

I have a dataframe of 12 columns, one column is just boolean; showing whether the given condition (dependent on other columns) is satisfied or not. That column is called "normality". I am trying to delete the rows of False values only if the row before and the row after that are True.

```
for s in range((dfm['normality'].count())):
    if dfm.loc[[s],('normality')] == False:
       if ((dfm.loc[[s+1],('normality')]) == True) & ((dfm.loc[[s-1],('normality')]) == True):
        dfm=dfm.drop(dfm.index[s])
else:
    ;
```

I have tried to use this code, yet I constantly get the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

on line 7 (the first if statement).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Could you share how your data looks like ?

Comment: You're passing a pandas series to an `if` statement, so it's trying to evaluate the truth value of an array, which is ambiguous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your row indexer is a list: `if dfm.loc[[s],('normality')] == False:`.
You should index without the list: `if dfm.loc[s,'normality'] == False:`